# Asio http supported versions?

Tags: http, boost-asio

Asio support only http 1.0? here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/client/async_client.cpp

It may possible to use the library for  http 1.1?

Comment: Asio is not an HTTP library; however, one could write an HTTP library using Asio.

Comment: The file you link to is an example of how to use it (A broken one for that matter since it says it is making an HTTP 1.0 request but then includes a Host header which wasn't introduced until HTTP 1.1.), not evidence of any native HTTP support.

Comment: As @TannerSansbury says "you could write an HTTP library using Asio" and I did (with a lot of help from Tanner via Stackoverflow) here: [via-httplib](https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib). It supports 1.0 & 1.1 now and I intend to support 2.0 soon. I recommend that you use the develop branch, it just needs a few doc updates before it becomes the master.